# How to write a jsonpath filter predicate which contains the IN operator within Postgres

Tags: postgresql, expression, predicate, jsonpath

I have a Expression within a SQL query which is looking for an object within a array and also use another property of the found object for another check.

It works for an equality check:

```
du.data @@ '$.some.data[*].** ? (@.propertyid == "1").anotherprop == "SomeValue"'
```

But I want to change it and use an "IN" operator like:

```
du.data @@ '$.some.data[*].** ? (@.propertyid == "1").anotherprop IN ["SomeValue","anotherValue"]'
```

Is there a way to achieve this without changing the whole logic? The statement is created by an querybuilder and I want to keep it.

I'm using PostgreSQL

I experimented with different styles of the IN operator but it seems not to work